# Streaming in C#2.0 IIS 5.1: localhost vs computer name

Tags: c#, http, iis-5

I am trying to create a webservice that returns streaming data.
For that I created a demo webservice, set 
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = false and
 I am writing to the same repsonse a few jpeg files flushing in between.

On the client side I am doing 
    loHttp = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
    loWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)loHttp.GetResponse();

now, if the url is http://localhost I get the information streaming as i want.
However, if the url is http://[mycomputername] then I get the information buffered, and only when **all** the jpegs are written only then do I get a response.
The only difference is how I access the computer.

What should I be configuring so I get a streaming experience also when accessing remote computer?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the culprit.

I was running fiddler in the background and it intercepted and buffered the response.